# Debugging rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, fixtures

Testing has been the thing I've avoided until I realized that with well written tests I can avoid having to enter console and running a string of commands over and over again. The big issue I'm having, however, is that when a test fails, I can't see much data to use to debug with. For example, when I'm testing models I need to see the models attributes, and I need to control when it's been built, created, and saved, and a way to detect these states. With rails fixtures and plain vanilla tests this is annoying to do.

How can I make debugging fixtures and rails tests easier? Is there a way to display more console-like information when a test fails? Which testing tools can I use to debug more easily? After all, debugging the tests themselves is a huge waste of time, and the biggest obstacle to using them in the first place.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use debugger with tests as for plain program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How use that to test models?

Comment: great! Please write your suggestion as an asnwer so i can give you credit, and add another detail I think is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging your tests is not very different from debugging your code.

Rails already comes with `byebug` gem (uncomment it, if necessary):

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
```

Now you are ready to put

```
debugger
```

line anywhere in your code.

Byebug supports many additional features, which you can find here: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug

Also check https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug project which provides even better experience for debugging.

Comment: I also found that byebug works well with pry. I can drop binding.pry instead of byebug and I get a nice colorful prompt. I *should* have the byebug commands as well but I don't, although the color prompt is pretty darn nice as well. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @ninja08 they have other cool features, keep reading it https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug

Answer (score 2):

Logging helps a lot to investigate and fix issues. Not only in test but also when you deploy it on production. You can log state of your models and other useful info. Also standard rails logging logs SQL that is send to the database so you can easily see what's going on there. SQL logging is on by default in dev and test and looks similar to this:

```
[2015-09-24 23:19:36 ledger DEBUG]:   [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
[2015-09-24 23:19:36 ledger DEBUG]:   [1m[35mSQL (2.1ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "projections_tags" ("ledger_id", "tag_id", "name", "authorized_user_ids") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["ledger_id", "ea9a68c5-c7c8-4964-b078-45bfc93d41ef"], ["tag_id", 9], ["name", "test"], ["authorized_user_ids", "{1}"]]
[2015-09-24 23:19:36 ledger DEBUG]:   [1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
```

I'm using [log4r](https://github.com/colbygk/log4r) as a logging library since it gives more control over the log output.

I also don't like debugging but in some cases it really helps. In this case [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) is your friend.

And of corse `rails console` and `rails dbconsole`